# Iterate by numpy ndindex: process killed

Tags: python, loops, numpy, multidimensional-array

I want to iterate over a multidimensional array  using the following function and then loop over list of limits

```
def H(x, y, low, upp): #x and y are multidim. arrays
a = np.ones(x.shape)
for index in np.ndindex(x.shape):
    if x[index] >= low and x[index] < upp:
        a[index] = y[index]
    else:
        a[index] = 0
return a

l_outputs = []
for i in range(list_of_limits.shape[0]):
    if list_of_limits[i] != 360:
        ans = H(x_array, y_array, list_of_limits[i], list_of_limits[i+1])
    l_outputs.append(ans)
```

The function and code work perfectly when I try small arrays (e.g. [4, 5, 3]) as inputs but once I try bigger arrays (e.g. [124, 10, 241, 320]) it runs for long time then I got "Killed", the whole process is killed and no outputs.

BTW the computer I am using is high performance one. So the problem with my code (loop or function) then is there a better way to do it and save run time or in how I run my script?

Example:

```
a = np.array([220,230, 240, 250, 260 ,270 ,280, 290, 300, 310, 320, 330,340, 350, 360, 370, 380, 390,400 ,410 ,420 ,430, 240, 250, 260 ,270 ,310, 320, 330, 410 ,420 ,430, 240, 230, 240, 250, 260 ,270, 420 ,430, 240, 360, 370, 380, 270, 420 ,430, 240, 360, 260,270 ,310, 320, 330,380, 270, 230, 240, 250, 420])       

a = a.reshape(4, 5, 3)

b = np.arange(60).reshape(4, 5, 3

ans = H(a, b, 260, 280)

print(ans)

[[[ 0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  4.  5.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.]]

 [[ 0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.]
  [24. 25.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.]]

 [[ 0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.]
  [36. 37.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0. 44.]]

 [[ 0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0. 49. 50.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0. 55.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.]]]
```

Comment: You can replace your function with `np.where(np.logical_and(x>=low,x<upp),0,y)`. Can you put an example of your expected output?

Comment: For example, if I have list of 10 different limits I would expect 10 arrays with the same dimensions as input arrays. Each output array would have same values of elements of y (input array) at the indices of x (input array) that have values within the applied limits and other elements would be zeros. 
I added an example to the post

Comment: Your code works much better with big arrays. I had just to switch 0 and y to get the result I want. 

Thanks